# Can't access the image through data-image property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview, actionviewhelper

I am facing trouble with this div element during loading the **image**. **404(Not Found)**

```
<div class="sidebar" data-color="purple" data-background-color="white" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg"></div>
```

Here is my code in Views. I am not familiar with this **data-image** tag. I have kept "sidebar-1.jpg" image inside my app/assets/images folder.

Now how can I solve this error and get the image works without harming other attributes(**data-color, data-background**) of this div element?

Plz help me

Answer (score 0):

The path should be `/assets/sidebar-1.jpg`

Hope it work.